# Change network mac address using "ip" command

Tags: networking, ip, ifconfig

Usually I would be able to change my wifi mac address with the ifconfig command like :

```
ifconfig <iface> hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Ubuntu have however deprecated ifconfig in behalf of the "ip" command, so I was wondering if there is an way to get similar functionality using that command?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First run:

```
ip link show
```

This will list your network devices. Find the one you want to change. Next, run:

```
sudo ip link set dev <your device here> down
```

Then:

```
sudo ip link set dev <your device here> address <your new mac address>
```

Finally:

```
sudo ip link set dev <your device here> up
```

Comment: `ip -c a` is really handy as a first command, or just `ip a` which stands for `ip address` and gives you a slightly different display including IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Comment: Will this change persist after the reboot?

Comment: If you want to persist this change, you should [use the `/etc/network/interfaces` file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366533/change-mac-address-permanently-inside-etc-network-interfaces) (but the question is titled *Change network mac address using "ip" command*